# Does changing a enum to a class break binary compat

Tags: java, class, enums, binary-compatibility

If I have a enum like this:

```
public enum Test {
    TEST_VALUE(42), OTHER_TEST_VALUE(1337);

    private int val;
    Test(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void increment() {
        val++;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
```

Do I break binary compat if I change it to something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static final Test TEST_VALUE = new Test(42);
    public static final Test OTHER_TEST_VALUE = new Test(1337);

    private int val;
    private final String oldEnumName;
    private Test(int val, String oldEnumName) {
        this.val = val;
        this.oldEnumName = oldEnumName;
    }

    public void increment() {
        val++;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public String name() {
        return oldEnumName;
    }

   public static Test valueOf(String name)
   ...
```

and add all other enum methods like "values" and "ordinal" to the new class? So other jars will be able to continue using it without recompiling?

Comment: For one, your class does not (and cannot) extend `Enum`.

Comment: I would guess yes, but I don't know for an absolute fact. Feels like it would take a minute or two to test it out, though. (And of course, special enum constructs like switches would break.)

Comment: Your constructor is different, so it's not the same

Comment: @cricket_007 The constructor doesn't really matter, since it's private; other jars won't be invoking it directly anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing with this enum to begin with

```
public enum Test {
    TEST_VALUE(42), OTHER_TEST_VALUE(1337);

    private int val;
    Test(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void increment() {
        val++;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

and then used this class to test:

public class EnumTesting {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Test enumClass : Test.values()) {
            enumClass.increment();
        }
        System.out.println(Test.OTHER_TEST_VALUE.name() + Test.OTHER_TEST_VALUE.getVal());
        System.out.println(Test.TEST_VALUE.name() + Test.TEST_VALUE.getVal());
        System.out.println("For name : " + Test.valueOf("TEST_VALUE"));
        System.out.println(Test.OTHER_TEST_VALUE.ordinal());
    }
}
```

Then I compiled the classes, and copied the EnumTesting class for future reference.
I changed the Test enum to this:

```
 public class Test {
    private static int globalOrdinal = 0;
    public static final Test TEST_VALUE = new Test(42, "TEST_VALUE");
    public static final Test OTHER_TEST_VALUE = new Test(1337, "OTHER_TEST_VALUE");

    private int val;
    private final String oldEnumName;
    private int ordinal;

    private Test(int val, String oldEnumName) {
        this.val = val;
        this.oldEnumName = oldEnumName;
        this.ordinal = globalOrdinal++;
    }

    public void increment() {
        val++;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public String name() {
        return oldEnumName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return oldEnumName;
    }

    public int ordinal() {
        return this.ordinal;
    }

    public static final Test[] VALUES = new Test[] {TEST_VALUE, OTHER_TEST_VALUE};

    public static Test[] values() {
        return VALUES;
    }

    public static Test valueOf(String oldEnumName) {
        for (Test enumClass : VALUES) {
            if (enumClass.oldEnumName.equals(oldEnumName))
            {
                return enumClass;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

and recomipled everything. The bytecode of the EnumTesting class stays the same after recompiling. So this is indeed a binary compatible change.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** a backwards compatible change, because the new class won't be a subclass of `java.lang.Enum`.

That actually does matter, because any time you have a generic defined as `<E extends Enum<E>>`, the bytecode will require the actual type to be a subclass of Enum. In particular, EnumSet and EnumMap won't work. (Other, similar classes may also break -- but those two are common enough that I think they merit special mention.)

To test this out, I started out with an enum class and four users of it:

```
public enum SoEnum {
  FOO, BAR
}
```

```java
public class SoUser {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SoEnum e = SoEnum.FOO;
    switch (e) {
      case FOO:
        System.out.println("a foo");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println(e.name());
    }
  }
}
```

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SoUserEnumMap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumMap<SoEnum,String> map = new EnumMap<>(SoEnum.class);
    map.put(SoEnum.FOO, "the foo");
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SoUserEnumSet {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumSet<SoEnum> set = EnumSet.of(SoEnum.FOO);
    System.out.println(set);
  }
}
```

```java
public class SoUserGeneric {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = getName(SoEnum.FOO);
    System.out.println(s);
  }

  static <E extends Enum<E>> String getName(E e) {
    return e.name();
  }
}
```

I compiled all of these, and then replaced SoEnum.java with a version that uses a normal class. (I hacked up a simple example, so it's a bit ugly :) ):

```
public class SoEnum {
  private SoEnum() {}

  public static SoEnum FOO = new SoEnum();
  public static SoEnum BAR = new SoEnum();

  public static SoEnum[] values() {
    return new SoEnum[] { FOO, BAR };
  }

  public int ordinal() {
    return this == FOO ? 0 : 1;
  }

  public String name() {
    return this == FOO ? "FOO" : "BAR";
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name();
  }
}
```

I recompiled only SoEnum.java, and then ran the rest. Interestingly enough, SoUser *did* work! It turns out that switch is actually handled by an anonymous class that the compiler creates for the lookup, which boils down to ordinals and static fields. That surprised me a bit!

But the other three use cases blew up spectacularly, and with error messages that would be extremely confusing if I didn't already know the root cause. The following is the error message from `java SoUserEnumSet`. The other two user classes failed in a similar way (even SoUserGeneric, which had I thought would fail in a slightly more standard ClassCastException).

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    SoUserEnumSet.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @3: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'SoEnum' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Enum'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @3
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { 'SoEnum' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b200 02b8 0003 4cb2 0004 2bb6 0005 b1

  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

Notice that because this is a link error, the "line" number (`@3`) doesn't even correspond to the source line -- it's the opcode offset in the .class file.

Note also that [JLS 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) specifies that you can't create a class that explicitly extends Enum (that is, you can't fix the `class SoEnum` by changing it to `class SoEnum extends Enum<SoEnum>`):

> It is a compile-time error if the ClassType names the class Enum or any invocation of Enum (§8.9).